# Error trying to use the waypoints in Here Routing API 7.2

Tags: javascript, here-api

[image: Is this Map will work for the below mentioned places?]

I'm facing issue in waypoint of origin and the destination place using Here Map API.

Because the waypoint which i am passing it shows me the error:

```
"NO ROUTE FOUND".
waypoint0:geo!78.44,17.43
waypoint1:geo!78.40,17.50
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Downvoted for more begging.

Comment: I think the issue is that the coordinates are on an island where there is no road network available in the data, hence you are getting the error. Are these the correct coordinates ?  I think you have exchanged the latitude, longitude. Try giving  waypoint0:geo!17.43,78.44 and waypoint1:geo!17.50,78.40

Comment: Thankyou so much it worked fine for me..Thanks alot..

Comment: How can i pass waypoint0, waypoint1 as dynamic? when i use this its not taking proper value.  'waypoint0': 'geo!lat,lng' I am getting values from var lat = location.Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude;
    var lng = location.Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude;

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned coordinates in your example are lying appr.30km away from the last route-able location in Longyearbyen, Svalbard. Even if you extend the transit radius this might be really to far away.

Comment: How can i pass waypoint0, waypoint1 as dynamic? when i use this its not taking proper value. 'waypoint0': 'geo!lat,lng' I am getting values from var lat = location.Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude; var lng = location.Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude;